# How to use configuration option set with project "by reference"

Tags: delphi, project, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

I've spent a couple of days exploring option sets (again) in XE3. They look really clever but either they are (still) broken or its me. What I wanted to do was to create a common option set file for a bunch of projects, say CommonOptions.optset. This is easy to create and edit using the View | Configuration Manager item. In this options set file I put a set of relative search paths such as:

```
..\..\source1;..\..\source2;
```

etc. These paths are proven to work when entered into the DEBUG or BASE build configuration directly. When I use the Configuration Manager to apply this common option set as a reference, the paths do not work. If I repeat the application using 'Modify Values' it works fine. To be sure, I deleted the DPROJ (and all the .local stuff too) and let Delphi recreate the DPROJ before applying the option set file as reference again. Still no luck.

I have several libraries with 10's of DPROJ's all of different vintages so I really do need a common way of specifying compiler options, don't include version info etc.

Has anyone got this reference thing to work?

Comment: Nope.  I'm in the middle of writing my own .Dproj editor tool to make it all work the way it should have worked. The current design is kludgy, over-complicated, and broken.

Comment: @Warren: I know how you feel. See a tool of my own just built: http://delphi-divining.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Very similar to what I was thinking of doing.  Since I might want different settings for debug and release, etc, I am thinking I'll stay with a minimal XML input file, and generate DPROJs from that.  Either that or else clean and sanitize all DPROJ files and just commit the sanitized versions to version control.

Comment: You can easily use DrojMaker to get multiple debug's release's etc. Simply name different markers in each area and list the relevant settings in the config file. Easy. Should work for FMX too.

Answer (score 0):

Referenced option sets are implemented as plain MSBuild imports. Therefore, all relative paths are relative to the importing project file. You can think of option sets as build configurations from which build configurations in referencing project files may inherit.